# Form checkboxes/radios need class change

Tags: jquery, attributes, checkbox, radio-button

I'm doing a form where the user has a list of options. Some radio buttons, some checkboxes. The user is probably wishy-washy  and will change their minds. I need to change the checked value in the input and also the class, so I can target those values through form submission. This needs to happen till the user clicks Submit. Here's what I have so far, which changes the "checked" attribute and class, but once the button is no longer selected, they don't change back. Help!

```
$("input:checkbox, input:radio").change(function() {
if ($("input:checked")) {
    $(this).attr("checked",true);
    $(this).addClass("checked");
} else {
    $(this).attr("checked",false);
    $(this).removeClass("checked");
}
});
```

**UPDATE**: Still nothing. I've pared it down to what's below and it still doesn't remove the class on change.

```
    $("input:checkbox, input:radio").change(function ()
   {
       if (this.checked)
      {
         $(this).addClass("checked");
      }
      else
       {
         $(this).removeClass("checked");
       }
   });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $(this).attr("checked",true);
    $(this).addClass("checked");
} else {
    $(this).removeAttr("checked");
    $(this).removeClass("checked");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/):

```
$(this).prop("checked",true);
```

And:

```
$(this).prop("checked",false);
```

See this question: [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)  for references why

Also change your code in general because in you version the 1st part of the statement with always be true if there is **any** checked box on your page:

```
$("input:checkbox, input:radio").change(function ()
{
    if (this.checked)
    {
        $(this).prop("checked", true);
        //also since it is a change event you probably 
        //don't need these prop() lines
        $(this).addClass("checked");
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).prop("checked", false);
        $(this).removeClass("checked");
    }
});
```

---

**UPDATE**:

With your update it seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/r7Yf6/

Comment: Cheers @Neal, he was trying to edit your answer so I rejected it and posted the comment instead. (afaik editing a post won't send any notification right?)

Comment: @shadow, don't believe it does (wait the OP was trying to edit my answer, why?)

Comment: @Shadow -- what was the OP adding to my answer?

Comment: @Neal exactly the same thing he added to his own question otherwise I would have added what he said to my own comment.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `if($(this).attr('checked'))` instead of `if ($("input:checked"))` ?
`attr` method is a getter or setter method according to the parameters you use.